# Comparing two numpy arrays for compliance with two conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

Consider two numpy arrays having the same shape, A and B, composed of 1s and 0s.  A small example is shown:

```
A = [[1 0 0 1]         B = [[0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 1 0]              [0 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0]              [1 1 0 0]
     [0 0 0 0]              [0 0 1 0]
     [0 0 1 1]]             [0 1 0 1]]
```

I now want to assign values to the two Boolean variables **test1** and **test2** as follows:

**test1**:  Is there at least one instance where a 1 in an `A` column and a 1 in the SAME `B` column have row differences of exactly 1 or 2?   If so, then **test1** = True, otherwise False.

In the example above, column 0 of both arrays have 1s that are 2 rows apart, so **test1** = True.   (there are other instances in column 2 as well, but that doesn't matter - we only require one instance.)

**test2**:  Do the 1 values in `A` and `B` all have different array addresses?  If so, then **test2** = True, otherwise False.

In the example above, both arrays have `[4,3] = 1`, so **test2** = False.

I'm struggling to find an efficient way to do this and would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Can you please provide your arrays in a useable format? Commas in between, and each one on a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to test if two arrays have an entry one element apart in the same column (only in one direction):

```
(A[1:, :] * B[:-1, :]).any(axis=None)
```

So you can do

```
test1 = (A[1:, :] * B[:-1, :] + A[:-1, :] * B[1:, :]).any(axis=None) or (A[2:, :] * B[:-2, :] + A[:-2, :] * B[2:, :]).any(axis=None)
```

The second test can be done by converting the locations to indices, stacking them together, and using `np.unique` to count the number of duplicates. Duplicates can only come from the same index in two arrays since an array will never have duplicate indices. We can further speed up the calculation by using `flatnonzero` instead of `nonzero`:

```
test2 = np.all(np.unique(np.concatenate((np.flatnonzero(A), np.flatnonzero(B))), return_counts=True)[1] == 1)
```

A more efficient test would use `np.intersect1d` in a similar manner:

```
test2 = not np.intersect1d(np.flatnonzero(A), np.flatnonzero(B)).size
```

Comment: Both test1 and test2 worked very well.   The code for test1 can easily be edited for row differences other that 2, but things might get out of hand if I need row-differences of, say, 10.   Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use masked_arrays and for second task you can do:

```
A_m = np.ma.masked_equal(A, 0)
B_m = np.ma.masked_equal(B, 0)

test2 = np.any((A_m==B_m).compressed())
```

And a naive way of doing first task is:

```
test1 = np.any((np.vstack((A_m[:-1],A_m[:-2],A_m[1:],A_m[2:]))==np.vstack((B_m[1:],B_m[2:],B_m[:-1],B_m[:-2]))).compressed())
```

output:

```
True
True
```

Comment: Your test2 was compact and efficient.

Comment: I liked your test1 approach, but it also gave 'true' for 0 values that met the conditions (not just 1 values).   This was fixed by having the vstacks operate on A and B, both unmasked.  Then, masked_equal was wrapped around each vstack.  Now it works super!  thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Test2: You could just check if they found any similar indexes found for a value of 1.

```
A =  np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 1]])
B = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0, 1]])
print(len(np.intersect1d(np.flatnonzero(A==1),np.flatnonzero(B==1)))>0))
```

Comment: This is probably better than my solution with `unique`, but you can simplify the check to `not np.intersect1d(np.flatnonzero(A), np.flatnonzero(B)).size`

Comment: test2 worked very well, but I added a 'not' to reverse the output.  Thank you.